# What is the gray bar in the Webkit frames timeline in Safari?

Tags: animation, safari, webkit, frame-rate, safari-web-inspector

I'm having performance issues where frame rates are dropping majorly during animations in Safari only, but I'm having trouble identifying the issues and looked at the frames timeline.  The problem is shakiness happening during animations.  I don't know if this is a css or JS issue since it is smooth in Chrome.

I'm noticing that the `Animation Frame` (purple) and the `Paint` (green) are at 60fps or better.  However, I notice a gray bar the extends past 60fps up to around 30fps.  I'm unable to find any information about what this is or how I could reference it in my code.  What is this gray bar indicative of? Thanks -[image of my frames timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh1Q1.png)